# Manipulate java List<Object> in Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I want to manipulate a Java List coming from a controller in my code JQuery (in JSP File).

My list is of type `List<Collaborateur>`.

This is my Controller action:

```
@GetMapping
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("collaborateurs"); //JSP name
    mv.addObject("collaborateurs", collaborateurService.getAll()); // ListName
    return mv;
}
```

And I want to show for example the property `email` for my second item in my list.

```
alert(${collaborateurs.get(2).getEmail});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your list will not exist in the JQuery "environnement". JQuery runs on the client part, your List stays on the server part. Usually, if I need this, I would use a variable to store the list parse into JSON to be use later in JQuery. The parse is done in JSP or Java to return a String value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple index access and variable name:

```
alert("${collaborateurs[2].email}");
```

Comment: I have just to mention that the quotes are obligatory : 
`alert("${collaborateurs[2].email}");`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.each` for accesseing every element of the list like this -

```
    var list = ${collaborateurs};
    $.each(list, function( index, value ) {
        alert( index + ": " + value.email );
    });
```